# Is there a pre-CSS3 way to make a div translated upwards the same amount as its height?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is equivalent to

```
<style>
 .bump-up { 
     height: 100px;
     margin-top: -100px; 
  }
</style>

<div class="bump-up">
    <p>This should translate the div upwards the same amount as it's height. For example, if the div is 100 pixels in height, then it will be translated 100 pixels higher than it otherwise would've been.
    </p>
</div>
```

except general enough that it doesn't need any exact pixels in the implementation. Is this possible without using CSS3's `transform:translateY(-100%)` property?

Comment: Not as such. Is there a specific issue you are trying to solve, or browser you need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using only css, this is possible with javascript however.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/84wbnbu9/1/))

HTML

```
<div id="moveMe">Hello World!</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#moveMe {
    position: relative;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var moveMe = document.getElementById("moveMe");
var docHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
var divHeight = moveMe.offsetHeight;
moveMe.style.top = ((docHeight / 2) - (divHeight / 2)) + "px";
```

Make sure to put your script after the DOM (or at the end of the body tag) or wrap the script with `window.onload = function() { /* script here */ }`